# Color cycle and forget plot

Tags: pgfplots, color, legend

I use `cycle list name=exotic` as coloring for my plots. I am looking for a way, either to use a number referring to a color (index from the exotic list), or a way to get the color of a labelled plot.

Here are an example of what I tried :

```
    \pgfplotsset{cycle list name=exotic}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[enlarge x limits=false]
        \addplot+[thick, no marks, domain=0:360, samples=50, forget plot]  {sin(x)};
        \addplot+[thick, no marks, domain=0:360, samples=50]  {cos(x)};
        \legend{plot 1, plot 2}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

But of course, the first plot is "forgotten" and therefore not taken into account for the color code.
(Accessing the color of a labelled plot would probably be useful, even if it exist a simpler solution.)

Answer (score 4):

I'll give here a general example how you can do this. The trick is to first define a `colormap` and then to convert this `colormap` to a `cycle list`. For other stuff you can then  access the colors of the `colormap` with the new feature `index of colormap` which was introduced in PGFPlots v1.13.

For more details have a look at the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.11,
        %
        % define a colormap that contains the colors you
        % want to use in the `cycle list'
        colormap={my colormap}{
            color=(red)
            color=(blue!50)
            color=(green!50!black)
            color=(orange)
        },
        % define some other `cycle list's to later combine them if you need
        % I will use here some predefined ones for simplicity
    }
    % now create a `cycle list' from that colors
    \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{my color cycle list}{
        [of colormap=my colormap]
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % some options to better visualize the result
            stack plots=y,
            every axis plot/.style={
                line width=2pt,
            },
            %
            % define here the `cycle list' you need
            cycle multiindex* list={
                my color cycle list
                    \nextlist
                [3 of]mark list
                    \nextlist
                linestyles
                    \nextlist
            },
        ]
            % add some plots
            \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
            \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
            \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
            \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};

            % if you want to use the color of the 2nd plot you can do this via
            % (you need index 1 here, because the index starts at 0)
            \node [index of colormap=1,anchor=south]
                at (0.25,2) {I am the 2nd color};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]